# Problems highcharts with data from php

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem I'm not able to solve.
I generate the full content of `data` with MySQL + PHP (localhost://createdata/mydata.php) and then copy and paste into the script.
In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jepeca/ej3bvj0u/) it works.

I did not get it to work feeding the data directly from the PHP file.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What error do you have in console? Could you show code which doesn't work? Make sure you are creating chart inside callback of AJAX.

Comment: @PawełFus It's no crossdomain, I need callback? This is de try:`jQuery.get('http://localhost/creajson/grafico_electronegatividad.php', null, function(data) {
     
     options.series[0].data = data;
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });`

Comment: Code looks okay.  If you have exactly the same JSON as you used in demo, then it's not proper JSON. For example `color:'#FF0000'` should be `"color":'#FF0000'`. Otherwise it will be treated as string.

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus, I made the changes in the quotes but does not work.
I guess I should stick with copy and paste:-(

Comment: Add line before creating chart: `console.log(typeof data, data)` to get format. In console you should have `Object ..data..`. If you have nothing, then `$.get()` doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Thank you very much Pawel. I will study the structure of the JSON because surely it is the problem. I will communicate progress.